# docker-machine create won't push instance onto AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-machine

Until now I've been creating and deploying Docker container onto AWS using:
`docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 flask_app` and it worked.
I don't know what has happened but now it just creates instance locally but
it won't push it on AWS.

What might be the problem ? It's leaving me perplexed.

**AWS screenshot:**

[image]

**Local docker machine screenshot:**

[image]

aws configure list:

[image]

Comment: Any errors you are seeing which might help to debug?

Comment: That's the thing, no errors whatsoever. I'd like to share errors with you if there were any.

Comment: Can you show us the output of "aws configure list".

Comment: The output is in updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the basics and make sure you are able to interact with AWS within your CLI environment and see if that works first. Next, I would try to see if there are anything extra indents in the credentials files as to why it's not working, and try to run the command with the access key and secret key in the command line like the example:

:docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key AKI******* --amazonec2-secret-key 8T93C*******  aws-sandbox

Comment: Strangely, it worked but I had to give it different instance name. At first it complained `"There is already a keypair with the name testdriven-prod.  Please either remove that keypair or use a different machine name."`  I was like "Where is it then ???" So I gave it different name and it is now running on EC2, however, I can see that I still can't connect to it publicly. When you search for 35.178.251.62:5001/users it will give you "Unable to connect".